# IE and FF show fav icon of one site on other site?

Tags: jsp, caching, web

We are facing a weird issue and need some brain storming here. I will try to provide as much detail as possible.

One of our clients, let's say "Client A" has reported many a times now that the fav icon shown in their browsers (they tried with both IE & FF) is not correct. They say that the icon they see is of one of our other clients "Client B".

The problem is that it's an intermittent issue and we have never been able to replicate it at our end. We tried on multiple machines spread over different geographical locations India, US, UK, Germany, etc.

Our client "Client A" is from UK and the icon which they see is of our client "Client B", which is from US & Germany. They have never seen any other client's icon. Its their own or Client B's.

We have multiple servers for load balancing and multiple Akamai servers for providing static content and all the servers are in US (although in the near future we will have a local server in UK & Germany).

We also checked the server logs to see if we could find anything weird, but nothing.

I guess it's an issue with caching, but how and where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you differentiating with your web servers sending output to Client A versus sending to Client B?  Presumably you have the same web server for both but you are not specifying any details.  Can you be more specific about how the web servers are set up?

Or do you have the same web server, and are specifying favicon via HTML?

Comment: We use multiple instances of Weblogic for our webserver with URL rewriting. All clients have separate pre-defined entry IPs mapped to separate instances of Weblogic.

Comment: So it's possible that Weblogic issending the wrong favicon.gif file.   Anything that you can do to re-check the ip-mapping?  You should also confirm that all of the other files received by Client A are correct.

Comment: Yep we did that. We even moved our Client A to a different IP, to see if that solves the issue and it worked for sometime (a month or 2), but it's back to haunt us. The beauty of the issue is that all the content js/css/img/etc, everything but the favicon is correct. and it only happens intermittently, and when it does, only the favicon is wrong and it's always of Client B.

Comment: It sounds like the error is coming from your Weblogic/ip mapping.  I'm convinced that it's not a browser problem, although the browser may be caching the incorrect favicon file once it receives it from the server.

Comment: That's true, it certainly is not a browser issue. But what I am surprised or should I say confused about, is that why only fav icon is getting changed and not anything else. If it's an issue with IP mapping going wrong or something, then all the static content should come wrong as it's all coming from one IP for one client.

Comment: The favicon file is the only file of type .ico -- maybe there are file type or MIME type settings that are set correctly for everything else.

Comment: hmmmm... That's something new to check for. Thanks will check it out and let you know something else comes up.

Comment: Thanks Mark. The issue finally got resolved. It turned out that our httpd.conf setup was crappy and was redirecting requests for static resources at/of/from the root directory of client A to client B.